# C# ASP.NET Middleware read Request Stream

Tags: c#, asp.net, middleware, httpcontext

I´ve got a Middleware for my ASP.NET WebApi, which should Log the Request in case its something we cannot work with. There for I´ve invented the following Attribute to declare which Methods uses the Middleware:

```
public class UseMiddlewareAttribute : Attribute
{
    public Type MiddlewareType { get; }

    public UseMiddlewareAttribute(Type middlewareType) 
    {
        MiddlewareType = middlewareType;
    }
}
```

And a example controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[DisableRequestSizeLimit]
[UseMiddleware(typeof(PlausibilityMiddleware))]
public async Task<ActionResult> ImportPersonsAsync(List<Person> persons) 
{
    return Ok(persons);
}
```

And here the middleware:

```
internal class PlausibilityMiddleware
{
    #region Fields

    private static readonly Logger Log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly IServiceProvider _provider;

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    public PlausibilityMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        _next = next;
        _provider = provider;
    }

    #endregion

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!CanProcess(context))
            {
                await _next(context);
                return;
            }

            var requestBody = DoSomeMagic();
            Log.Trace(requestBody);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // do not skip _next(context) ---> This method calls the Controller behind
            Log.Error("Unknown error occured while validate pre import");
            Log.Error(ex);
        }

        await _next(context);
    }

    private bool CanProcess(HttpContext context)
    {
        var endpoint = context.Features.Get<IEndpointFeature>()?.Endpoint;
        var attribute = endpoint?.Metadata.GetMetadata<UseMiddlewareAttribute>();

        return attribute != null && attribute.MiddlewareType.Equals(GetType());
    }
```

Firstly the `context.Features.Get<IEndpointFeature>()?.Endpoint` returns null, so I cannot access the attributes, also I don´t know how to read Request-Body.

Answer (score 0):

To access the given Attribute I needed to configure the app, it´s neccessary to Add the Middleware between `UseRouting` and `UseEndpoint`:

```
            app
            .UseRouting()
            .UseMiddleware<PlausibilityMiddleware>()
            .UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            })
```

To read the Request-Body I need to `EnableBuffering` and use a `StreamReader`. But then the StreamReader disposes the underlying Stream, so the Controller cannot access the Stream anymore. You can use `CopyTo` and use another `MemoryStream` but that is overhead. StreamReader has a Consturctor parameter `leaveOpen` finaly:

```
    private static async Task<string> DoSomeMagic(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Request.EnableBuffering();

        using var reader = new StreamReader(context.Request.Body, leaveOpen: true);

        var result = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        context.Request.Body.Position = 0;

        return result;
    }
```

Also its nice to know you cannot access the stream as synchronously read `ReadToEnd()` if you want to, you need to set `AllowSynchronousIO = true`

```
    var syncIOFeature = httpContext.Features.Get<IHttpBodyControlFeature>();
    if (syncIOFeature is not null)
        syncIOFeature.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
```

Then you can ReadToEnd as Synchronously method.